# elastalert with Slack in HELK

Tags: elastic-stack, elastalert

I am still new with [HELK](https://github.com/Cyb3rWard0g/HELK/tree/master) but i m getting the hang of it. Currently i am trying to use the elastalert function in HELK. I already followed every steps from an [article](https://posts.specterops.io/what-the-helk-sigma-integration-via-elastalert-6edf1715b02) that i found. The alerts still not sending to my Slack channel/myself. All HELK setup and running on docker. everytime i made a change into the yaml file i always kill the docker and start it back but still nothing happens
This is my configuration

```
   helk-elastalert:
    image: otrf/helk-elastalert:latest
    container_name: helk-elastalert
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: "5"
        max-size: "6m"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - helk-logstash
    environment:
      ES_HOST: helk-elasticsearch
      ES_PORT: 9200
      SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: https://hooks.slack.com/services/<random-string>/<random-string>/<random-string>
    networks:
      helk:
```

This is his configuration

```
 helk-elastalert:
  build: helk-elastalert/
  container_name: helk-elastalert
  restart: always
  depends_on:
    — helk-elasticsearch
    — helk-kibana
  environment:
    ES_HOST: helk-elasticsearch
    ES_PORT: 9200
    SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: https://hooks.slack.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 networks:
   helk:
```

*Please do note that this is an old article so maybe this my configuration maybe a bit different from him.

There is also a [script](https://github.com/Cyb3rWard0g/HELK/blob/master/docker/helk-elastalert/scripts/elastalert-entrypoint.sh) that he created to add the slack_webhook_url in the elastalert rule but when i try to run this script only *# *********** Setting Slack Integration ************** that is not running. I already have no idea how to make it work. Please help me

This is how the output should be
[kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD5Lp.png)

[slack receiving alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc4Bx.png)